# jQuery bootstrap date range picker with months only view mode

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, twitter-bootstrap-3, daterangepicker

I need a jQuery date range picker that combines the features of these following two great plug-ins.
In [bootstrap-daterangepicker](http://www.dangrossman.info/2012/08/20/a-date-range-picker-for-twitter-bootstrap/) I'm missing the ability to define only months view mode. And in [bootstrap-datepicker](http://eternicode.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker) I'm missing few things:

- The ability to use only one input field to represent the range and show the selected range inside it (using the defined format and separator)
- A validation that the "from" is earlier than the "to" (preferably disabling all earlier dates in the "to" calendar - like the first plug-in does).
- Configuring predefined date ranges ranges (last year, last month, etc. ) - That's a nice to have :)

Can anyone recommend such a plug-in that has all these mentioned features? Or recommend the best way to add the missing features to one of them?

Comment: Though the two first points I mentioned missing in bootstrap-datepicker, are quite easily achieved adding event handlers, as demonstrated here: http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/ in the last example. I decided to extend 'bootstrap-daterangepicker' to support a month view mode. It's almost ready, stay tuned...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to extend 'bootstrap-daterangepicker' to support month view mode. I've posted a pull request, but you can find my version here.

https://github.com/rklachko/bootstrap-daterangepicker/tree/month-view